# Is there a term of art (or even better, a plugin) for displaying function definitions without having to jump between files?

Tags: c++, function, user-interface, ide, editor

#### Wait!—

Before voting to close this question for asking "to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource," I humbly ask for a chance to disclaim subjectivity—after all, that guideline was primarily designed to prevent questions "attract[ing] opinionated answers and spam." Frankly I've been afraid to ask this question here, but I keep coming back to it month after month, so I'm taking my chances. I feel it's very much a ["practical, answerable problem[...] unique to software development,"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and definitely about "software tools commonly used by programmers," because I'm only interested in solutions centered around common, free editors and IDEs such as Notepad++, Sublime, and Eclipse ((un)fortunately my company doesn't easily license Visual Studio).

---

#### Background (feel free to skip)

I work with C++ code so old that we use `typedef`'ed `int`s instead of `bool`s (`bool` wasn't standardized until C99). Okay, that's just a silly example of antiquity—more to the point, I work with design patterns that probably seemed like great ideas at the time, but have turned out to be extremely difficult to understand / maintain / extend—singleton factories, a "honeycomb matrix" (can't even find this in any design pattern books), and way too many `static` hashes and `friend` classes seemingly introduced to cheat through the complexities when enhancements were needed. Sometimes, the level of abstraction is *insane*—6, 7, 8 levels of derived classes ([*diamonds of death*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) along the way)—and in my experience no (free) Intelli-whatever has been able to figure out exactly which implementation of a virtual function is being called. Even if I found a reliable jump-to-function-definition tool, the problem isn't that—it only took five years, but I know my away around what's where now—the *problem* is that I can't store more than 3 or 4 function definitions in my mind as I try to understand one function that's calling the others, passing references around (too often, return values are near-useless `OK` indicators). I partially solved this problem by getting a 2560x1440 monitor and installing WinSplit Revolution so I can have four quadrants of files open on my screen—but as you can imagine, it is a P.I.T.A. to open files on four different windows—sometimes I even need to open the same (gigantic) files on two separate windows.

---

### Question

There's one thing I can imagine would make my life so, so, so much better—**being able to see function definitions *without* having to jump between files.**

1. I cannot find one—maybe because I lack the term of art (*e.g.* googling "inline function definitions"  mostly returns results about inline functions)—but has anyone encountered a plugin (or a reasonably popular / well-supported and preferably free editor / IDE) that gives the ability to see the function definition of a call *without* having to lose visibility of the calling context?
2. If not, does anyone with experience in developing plugins for Notepad++ or Sublime have thoughts on whether it'd be *possible* (or on the other hand, difficult or impossible) to implement a plugin that, ideally, could show function definitions by expanding "+"-trees, *e.g.* UltraEdit  allows you to collapse/expand bracketed blocks—

   [image]

   Being able to expand function calls to function definitions in a similar way (but coloring the background grey to indicate its read-only-ness) would be immensely useful. But even if not that sophisticated, something like split panes might work. I have no experience with plugin development for editors, so I don't know what the limitations are of their development APIs. If such a plugin were possible though, I'd write it myself!

If this question gets closed, so be it—I don't know where else I'd ask such a question (the community here is top-notch)—but I'll understand if it's deemed off-topic. Thanks anyway for reading and giving it a chance.

Comment: Since you asked nicely and seem to put forth some effort to demonstrate why this question shouldn't be closed, I'll refrain from voting to close it.  Alas, I can't help you as I don't use such a tool, nor would I ever want to.  But that's me.

Comment: That sounds more like a feature request for particular IDEs ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Ah, sorry if it sounds so. I'm more than willing to write it myself. Because I've only been using `vim` and UltraEdit (a proprietary IDE, mandated by my team), I'm not familiar with the world of Notepad++, Sublime, even Eclipse—I felt anyone but me would have much better perspective—and with a little guidance I could go forth and look into plugin development.

Comment: @acheong87 I'm afraid there will be only possible answers for solutions within particular IDE frameworks, that can't be really generalized (not that I have a good Idea for a particular one ...).

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about [Code Bubbles](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsPX0nElJ0k) but I've never seen it in actual practice.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It appears that Andrew Bragdon, the person behind Code Bubbles has disappeared into Microsoft.  The upside: [Debugger Canvas](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4a979842-b9aa-4adf-bfef-83bd428a0acb), the downside is you'll probably never see it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, @Speed8ump - that does seem like something I'd use. I also found [Light Table](http://www.chris-granger.com/lighttable/), which looks great, but doesn't support C++ (yet). I'll keep searching...

Comment: Thanks for holding off on closing this question, everyone. I really appreciate people giving it a chance. I'm self-voting-to-close this question now, but will comment back here if I ever find the IDE of my dreams.

Answer (score 0):

It is not free, but I've recently released [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension for Visual Studio 2015 to solve exactly this problem - prevent jumping between files by displaying several functions from different classes in one window.